# Exchange not allowing emails to invalid addresses for SAP

Tags: exchange-2007

I have a client who sends out emails from SAP via their Exchange server.

Emails are received ok by recipients, however if an email is sent to an invalid address there is no bounceback to the sender.

Users need these bouncebacks to work.

Bounceback emails are received ok when sending from Outlook.

I have traced the issue to their Exchange 2007 server.  When trying to send a test email to an invalid email address using their Acronis backup system the following message is received:

The server cannot accept DATA command.

Other Acronis setups I work with can send emails to invalid addresses (i.e. bounceback emails are received).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the header here from a SAP email to an existing address?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it's the reply or from header's in SAP's email generation that are the issue.  SAP may not be sending as the users email address.  Can you post the header here from a SAP email to an existing address?

There are two ways remote email servers will handle invalid addresses:

1. reset connection: they will just drop the connection from your exchange server.  In this case the Exchange server will send an email to the sending account's from address saying it can't send the message.
2. accept and delete: remote email server looks like it accepts message. Your exchange server  thinks it was sent.  remote server just silently deletes email since it's to a invalid mailbox.
3. accept and reject: remote email server looks like it accepts message. Your exchange server  thinks it was sent. remote server sends a email to the from/reply address saying user not found to your exchange server.